# What is 誘われて (Sasowarete) in this song lyric?

Tags: て-form, passive-voice

I am a beginner Japanese student, and I'm going through a song and translating it. I am struggling to understand the word 誘われて in the first line. I understand that the verb is 誘う; is this the -te form? I thought the -te form would be 誘って.

The full context is this:

> 真っ白な景色にいま誘われて
>   僕は行くよ　まだ見ぬ世界へ

I would appreciate any help! Bonus points if you can guess the song :)

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17330/9831 . https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28239/9831

Answer (score 7):

The base 誘う's te-form would be 誘って, but it's not just the basic 誘う.

> 誘う = base
>
> 誘われる = passive form
>
> 誘われて = passive form's te-form

In your song it indicates **to be** invite**d** by something/someone.

Comment: thank you! I understand now :)

Answer (score 4):

誘われて is a て-form, but not of 誘う, which would be 誘って, as you correctly note.

Rather, it is the て-form of the passive conjugation of 誘う, which is 誘われる. 誘われて would mean "(I) am/was invited", with the tense as usual determined by the end-of-sentence verb.

Does that help you to piece together the rest of the translation?

Comment: yes! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

誘われて is the passive -te form, usually understood by the final verb. However, this -te form (as a standard grammatical construct) may simply end the first part of a compound sentence, such as your example:

真っ白な景色にいま誘われて
僕は行くよ　まだ見ぬ世界へ

and, as it were, the same is true of first sentence of KAWAKAMI Hiromi's short story "Kamisama"

くまにさそわれて散歩に出る。

Band: Nico touches the Wall Song title: HOLOGRAM
Song for Full Metal Alchemist
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JwYgd4zHvU

Comment: KAWAKAMA Hiromi <- Kawakam**i** ?